# Subtracting 2 pointers returned by malloc with zero size

Tags: c, malloc, language-lawyer

I have a queue data structure defined as (`NULL` checks omitted for simplicity)

```
struct ml_queue {
    void *buf;
    void *next_elemnt;
    size_t size;
}

struct ml_queue *ml_queue_alloc(size_t size){
    struct ml_queue *mq_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*mq_ptr));
    void *buf = malloc(size);
    ml_queue->buf = buf;
    ml_queue->size = size;
    ml_queue->next_element = buf;
    return ml_queue;
}

bool ml_queue_is_empty(struct ml_queue *queue){
    char *buf = queue->buf;
    char *next = queue->next;
    char *limit = buf + queue->size;
    return limit - buf > 0; //Here is the question
}
```

The thing that I'm not sure is if such an implementation causes UB when working with zero-sized queues. Like

```
struct ml_queue *q = ml_queue_alloc(0);
bool is_empty = ml_queue_is_empty(q); //UB?
```

As known `malloc` returns an object of size passed as a parameter. Arrays cannot be empty by definition.

But can we consider that `malloc(0)` allocates an array of zero-size object with 1 element? The object is defined at the section 3.15 of the Standard as

> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

It is not specified it can be empty. While neither array nor struct can consist of zero members.

Comment: isn't the code wrong, what use does the `next` have there? In any case, result of subtraction is of type `ptrdiff_t` which is signed - the result need not representable for very large arrays - better to use comparison operators with pointers!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala next is a pointer to the next element of the queue

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes the pointer subtract result does not have to. It can be solved by restricting of creating queues with size more the PTRDIFF_MAX. This is not an issue here.

Comment: But you can always compare `next < limit` say.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree that it would be better here. But as far as I can tell such comparison would also yield UB in case a zero size queue created.

Comment: only if it is a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `malloc(0)` returns is implementation defined behavior.

As per C11 standard (n1570) section on [Implementation-defined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.3.12):

> Whether the `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc` functions return a null pointer or a
>   pointer to an allocated object when the size requested is zero (7.22.3).

So you will have to look up the documentation of your specific implementation to answer this question.

Comment: So to make it portable it seems better  to handle `0` - sized allocations explicitly?

Comment: Yes. That is how I would do it.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.5.6 Additive operators(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) - `"When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object"`